# Pra que serve o comando LOCK TABLES?

Tags: mysql

Esses dias me deparei com um trecho de um SQL que tinha o comando `LOCK TABLES`.

Eu nunca tinha visto isso antes e, pelo pouco que pude ver, parece-me que isso seria para travar a tabela durante a inserção ou atualização.

Mas eu queria poder entender melhor o funcionamento:

- Como funciona `LOCK TABLES`? Gostaria de alguns exemplos.
- Quando eu devo usar esse comando?
- Devo evitar usar esse comando em alguns casos? Existe algum risco?

Comment: Quem deu o negativo aí pode explicar o motivo, hein?

Comment: Enquanto uma tabela está bloqueada pelo `LOCK TABLES`, a próxima query fica em uma "fila" até a liberação? E se a próxima query também tiver `LOCK TABLES`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Como funciona LOCK TABLES? Gostaria de alguns exemplos.

Simplesmente faz o lock explícito da tabela, bloqueando exclusivamente para sessão que executou o comando.
Documentação do MySQL: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html:

> "A table lock only protects against inappropriate reads or writes by
>   other sessions"

Ou seja, protege os registros durante alguma alteração

Exemplo:

```
LOCK TABLES nome-da-tabela WRITE;

... comandos ...

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

`LOCK TABLES` pode fazer dois tipos de lock:

`LOCK TABLES READ`: bloqueia para leitura e permite ler uma tabela bloqueada. Multiplas sessões podem usar esse lock ou mesmo tempo.

`LOCK TABLES WRITE`: bloqueia para alterações. Somente uma sessão pode executar esse bloqueio por vez.

### Quando eu devo usar esse comando?

Você deve usar quando deseja que, durante alguma alteração (insert, update ou delete) outros usuários não tenham acesso à tabela.

> "Locks may be used to emulate transactions or to get more speed when
>   updating table"

Ou seja, para trabalhar como se estivesse numa transação ou melhorar a performance. Uma sequência de comandos que exija muita alteração por exemplo é um caso que pode ser usado o `lock tables`.

### Devo evitar usar esse comando em alguns casos? Existe algum risco?

A não ser para uma operação muito específica, não deve usar esse comando. 
O mysql automaticamente faz o lock necessário quando executa alterações, inclusive um lock de linha e não de tabela quando necessário, por isso deixe o `mysql` gerenciar isso.
O risco é óbvio: deixar a tabela locada, deixando o banco lento e prejudicando outras operações.

Diferente de um `lock` que a *engine* do `mysql` faz, a tabela não sairá do lock automaticamente, sendo necessário executar `UNLOCK TABLES` ao final do processo.

Answer (score 6):

Para usar LOCK TABLES, você precisa do privilégio global LOCK TABLES e de um privilégio SELECT sobre as tabelas envolvidas.

As principais razões para usar LOCK TABLES são para emular transações ou para obter maior velocidade ao atualizar tabelas.

**LOCK TABLES funciona da seguinte maneira:**

- Ordena todas as tabelas a serem bloqueadas em uma ordem definida internamente (do ponto de vista do usuário, a ordem é indefinida).
- Se uma tabela for bloqueada com um bloqueio de leitura e um de gravação, colocará o bloqueio de gravação antes do de leitura.
- Bloqueia uma tabela de cada vez até que a thread obtenha todos os bloqueios.

A politica garante que o bloqueio de tabelas esteja livre de deadlosks*. Há, todavia, outras coisas das quais você deve estar ciente com este esquema:

Se você estiver usando um bloqueio de gravação LOW_PRIORITY em uma tabela, isso significa apenas que o MySQL esperará por este bloqueio específico até que não existam threads que queiram um bloqueio de leitura. Quando a thread possuir o bloqueio de gravação e estiver esperando para obter o bloqueio da próxima tabela na lista de tabelas a bloquear, todas as outras threads esperarão pelo bloqueio de gravação ser liberado. Se isto se tornar um problema sério com a sua aplicação, você deverá converter algumas das suas tabelas em tabelas de transação.

Você pode terminar com segurança uma thread que estiver esperando por um bloqueio de tabela com KILL.

Observe que você não deve bloquear tabelas que estivar usando com INSERT DELAYED. Isto porque, neste caso, INSERT é feito por uma thread separada.

Normalmente, você não tem de bloquear tabelas porque todas as declarações UPDATE únicas são atomicas, nenhuma outra thread pode interferir com alguma outra declaração SQL correntemente em execução. Há alguns casos nos quais você gostaria de bloquear tabelas de qualquer forma:

- Se você for executar muitas operações em múltiplas tabelas, é muito mais rápido bloquear as tabelas que você for usar. O problema é que nenhuma outra thread pode atualizar uma tabela com bloqueio de leitura e nenhuma outra thread pode ler uma tabela bloqueada para gravação.

  O motivo pelo qual algumas coisas são mais rápidas sob LOCK TABLES é que o MySQL não descarregará a cache de chaves das tabelas bloqueadas até que UNLOCK TABLES seja chamada (normalmente a cache de chaves é descarregada após cada declaração SQL). Isto aumenta a velocidade de inserção, atualização e exclusão em tabelas MyISAM.
- Se você estiver usando um mecanismo de armazenamento no MySQL que não suporte transações, deverá usar LOCK TABLES se quiser assegurar-se de que nenhuma outra thread fique entre um SELECT e um UPDATE. O exemplo mostrado aqui requer LOCK TABLES para executar rapidamente:

  ```
  mysql> LOCK TABLES trans READ, clientes WRITE;
  mysql> SELECT SUM(valor) FROM trans WHERE id_do_cliente=algum_id;
  mysql> UPDATE cliente SET valor_total=soma_das_declarações_anteriores
      ->   WHERE id_do_cliente=algum_id;
  mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
  ```

  Sem UNLOCK TABLES há uma chance de outra thread inserir uma nova linha na tabela trans entre a execução das declarações SELECT e UPDATE.

> *Deadlock no contexto de banco de dados(MS-SQL/MySQL), caracteriza uma situação em que ocorre um impasse e dois ou mais processos ficam impedidos de continuar suas execuções, ou seja, ficam bloqueados.

Fonte: MySQL Guia de Estudo para Certificação (tradução: Acauan Fernandes)

Esta matéria também está publicada em [6.7.5. Sintaxe LOCK TABLES e UNLOCK TABLES](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/lock-tables.html)

O Manual está disponível on-line em diversos formatos e línguas no Web site da MySQL AB (http://www.mysql.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa que me confundiu um pouco e acho que não ficou bem esclarecido é que:

- Read locks são locks “compartilhados”, eles previnem que um write lock seja adquirido, mas não outro read lock, ou seja outras sessões podem ler tabela, só não poderão gravar até que seja liberado o lock.
- Write locks são “exclusivos”, previnem qualquer outro lock tanto de escrita, como de leitura, outra sessões que tentar ler ou gravar algum registro, ficará em estado de espera, até que seja liberado o lock.